# Convert Abbreviated numbers to full decimal values

Tags: r, numbers, type-conversion

In R I have a dataset containing abbreviated numbers, I really want the full metric so I can sum the values... is there a library or something that would aid in this effort?

i.e.

```
start  result
5k = 5,000
.5k = 500
.25k = 250
5m = 5,000,000
.5m = 500,000
```

and so on...

Data

```
dd <- data.frame(start = c('5k', '.5k', '.25k', '5m', '.5m'),
                 result = c('5,000', '500', '250', '5,000,000', '500,000'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any library.Just declare k=1000.And add * operator in between.
What's the big deal in it.No need for different Library.

Comment: While that is the function I want to perform, a library would be handy to deal with splitting the character string giving me everything to the left... performing the operation for all abbreviations and giving me a numeric in the end... If one does not exist when I'd write a robust function and package it...